# Remove multiple elements from ConcurrentDictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the follow code:

```
public class Item
{
   public string key { get; set; }
   public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
private ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> StorageItems { get; set; }

private void Reload(IEnumerable<Item> newItems)
{
  foreach (Item item in newItems)
    {
      StorageItems.AddOrUpdate(item.key, item.Value, (s, o) => item.Value);
    }

 // TODO remove from StorageItems the items that newItems does not contains
 }
```

I Have the follow idea, but I am not sure about to remove elements from the ConcurrentDictionary inside the loop body:

```
private void ReloadIdea(IEnumerable<Item> newItems)
    {
        List<string> addedOrUpdatedKeys = new List<string>();

        foreach (Item item in newItems)
        {
            StorageItems.AddOrUpdate(item.key, item.Value, (s, o) => item.Value);

            addedOrUpdatedKeys.Add(item.key);
        }

        foreach (string key in StorageItems.Keys)
        {
            if (!addedOrUpdatedKeys.Contains(key))
            {
                string removedValue;

                StorageItems.TryRemove(key, out removedValue); // <-- Removing items from collection that is iterating ??
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Removed misleading code change.

Since it is a `ConcurrentDictionary`, race conditions are already taken care of by the collection itself. Additionally, it does not suffer from the dreaded "collection was modified while enumerating" error if you modify it during a foreach loop.

Comment: Thanks. It is because is a ConcurrentDictionary. I can not modify it during a foreach loop if I am using a common Dictionary or a List, right?

Comment: Yup, normal dictionary is essentially immutable during iterations. Next iteration will raise the exception I mentioned.

Comment: I need to known if StorageItems contains a key that is not in addedOrUpdatedKeys. It is the reason because I check if (!addedOrUpdatedKeys.Contains(key)) before try to remove.

Comment: My bad! Shouldn't have removed that `if()`, yes that if() is needed but you need not worry about modifications as CD doesn't throw like the normal one.